# Рейтинг статьи в процентах

Tags: php

Имеются две переменные:

```
$likes = 100; //кол-во лайков статьи
$dislikes = 10; //кол-во дизлайков статьи
```

как в итоге получить рейтинг в процентах? например `90`, но не больше 100 и что бы в минус не уходило

Comment: А если dislikes будет -1000, с сотней likes, тогда сколько будет итоговый процент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения лайков в процентах, используйте такую формулу:

```
ПРОЦЕНТ = (100/($LIKES+$DISLIKES)*$LIKES)
```

P.S. Число может быть дробным, поэтому округляем любым удобным способом.

P.S.2. Есть ситуация когда после округления может быть 0, правильней всего такую ситуацию сразу предусмотреть и если получилось 0, то заменять на 1.

Comment: Тут скорее будет floor(100 * ($likes + $dislikes) / abs(likes  - $dislikes)) (подправил для положительных $dislikes)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Автор вроде наглядно показал что дислайки всегда положительные.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov  при условии того, что числа положительны, у вас там 1 вечная в формуле.

Comment: спасибо. ваше решение мне подходит.